# I made this set of functions but I don't know why I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined

Tags: javascript

> I don't know why I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: username is not defined

The idea behind the functions is to create input elements and then append them to a form and overlay

```js
         
         const signup_nav = document.querySelector(".signUp");
         //create elements       
        //The first function create an element input type
         function createInput(variableNames, inputType, inputClass, inputPlaceholder) {
       let variableNames = document.createElement("input");
       variableNames.type = " ' " + inputType + " ' ";
       variableNames.placeholder = " ' " + inputPlaceholder + " ' ";
       variableNames.className = inputClass;
       return variableNames;
        }
      
        //The second one create the inputs 
        //create inputs

        function createForm() {
       createInput(username, text, username_input, Username);
       createInput(email, email, email_input, Email);
       createInput(password, password, password_input, Password1);
       createInput(retype_password, password, retype_passwordInput, Password2);
       createInput(submit_signup, submit, submit_signup, Submit);
       return createInput();
        }

         //And the last one append everything to a form and finally to an overlay
        //append element to parent element
        function createFull() {
       //create overlay div
       const overlay = document.createElement("div");
       overlay.className = "overlay";
       document.querySelector("body").appendChild(overlay);
      //create div element
      //append it to the main overlay
       const overlayWrapper = document.createElement("div");
       overlayWrapper.className = "overlayWrapper";
       overlay.appendChild(overlayWrapper);
         //create form
         //append it to wrapper div
       const form_signup = document.createElement("form");
       form_signup.className = "form_signup";
       overlayWrapper.appendChild(form_signup);
         //append inputs to the form
       form_signup.appendChild(createForm());
       return overlay;
        }
        //click event - display overlay
        //call the last function on click event
        signup_nav.addEventListener("click", (ev) => {
     let evObject = ev.target;
     ev.preventDefault();
       if(evObject.className === "signUp" && evObject.tagName === "A") {
      console.log(evObject);
      createFull();
       }
        });
```

The functions are really easy, but I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: It says "username" is not defined. What is unclear about that? Do you have some reason to think it should be defined?

Comment: You have not defined "username" variable. Do you want to get the value of username from the DOM as you might have set the id as "username" and are confusing it with a variable name?

Comment: I don't want to take the username element from the DOM, I just want to generate it using the function and append it on click

Answer (score 0):

In

```
 function createForm() {
          createInput(username, text, username_input, Username);
```

You are using Username with capital "U", in other places you only seen to reference lowercase only for fields AND variables. Maybe it's a typo?